# HtmlInputCheckBox Not Check when Selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to check a :checked state of checkbox but it's not registering as checked when debugging my code. From what I've read on other stackoverflow articles, the following code should work. Unless there's something I'm missing?

C#:

```
protected void MarkAsRead(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem aItem in rptInbox.Items)
            {
                HtmlInputCheckBox chkDisplayTitle = (HtmlInputCheckBox)aItem
                                                         .FindControl("chkDisplayTitle");
                if (chkDisplayTitle.Checked)
                {
                    var messageid = chkDisplayTitle.Value;
                }
            }
       }
```

HTML:

```
<input id="chkDisplayTitle" type="checkbox" class="i-checks" runat="server" 
       value='<%# Eval("MessageId")%>' />
```

Repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptInbox" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr class="<%# Eval("MessageRead")%>">
                                <td class="check-mail">
                                    <input id="chkDisplayTitle" type="checkbox" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("MessageId")%>' />
                                </td>
                                <td class="mail-ontact"><a href="mail_detail.aspx?id=<%# Eval("MessageId")%>"><%# Eval("FromUser")%></a></td>
                                <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.aspx?id=<%# Eval("MessageId")%>"><%# Eval("Subject")%></a></td>
                                <td class=""><%# Eval("Attachment")%></td>
                                <td class="text-right mail-date"><%# Eval("MessageDateTime")%></td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're using HtmlInputCheckBox over CheckBox?

Comment: I assumed it might be easier to find in the repeater?

Comment: They are just as easy to find, however there is more logic built around remembering and loading values for CheckBox.  HtmlInputCheckBox assumes you are taking over control of some basic functionality.

Comment: @LianeStevenson - I tried with your mark-up it's working fine for me. I am not sure what is causing the issue for you.

Comment: When the page loads it rebinds the repeater to the data - could that be the issue?

Comment: `private void GetMsgs(int user)
        {
            MailboxController mailcontroller = new MailboxController();
            MessageCollection msgs = mailcontroller.GetMsgs(user);

            rptInbox.DataSource = msgs;
            rptInbox.DataBind();
        }`

This is called when loading the page

Comment: Yep that got it - it's the postback